# R-Wrap barplot around circle

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, data-visualization

Is it possible to wrap a barplot around a circle like this image?

[image]

I've tried using `coord_polar()` without any luck

Comment: This is a Circos plot. Check out `RCircos` it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot